# How to load specific fields from a nested relationship with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `Order` model which belongs to a `User` and has `Revision`s.

When I try to load orders including: the `'id'` and `'name'` field from its user and some fields including `'user_id'` field from whole revisions, I do:

```
return Order::with(array('user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id','name');
    }), 'revisions' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id','created_at','user_id','operation','text');
    })->get();
```

However, I'd like to get the *name* of the user, which naturally is at `users` table as `'name'` field.

#### Relationships setup

**Order**

```
  public function user() {

    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }


  public function revisions() {
    return $this->hasMany('Revision');
  }
```

**Revision**

```
  public function order() {

    return $this->belongsTo('Order');
  }
```

**User**

```
  public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
  }

  public function revisions() {
     return $this->hasMany('Revision');
   }
```

#### Expected result

Just for fast typing reasons I represent it as a JS object ...

```
orders = [

  { id: 5,
    user: {....},
    revisions: [
      { id:100,
        operation: 'Creation',
        text: 'Please provide soon',
        user: 'John Doe'  // Here I got the name instead of a user_id
      }
    ]
  },

  {...}
]
```

How can I complete this?

#### Note

I did the proper relationship setups at each model.

Comment: and what result do you get ?

Comment: I'm getting revisions with the user_id at each revision which is a number. I'd like to get the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, you get `user_id` in `revisions` because it is a property of revision itself, you should look for the username in the `Order` object returned

```
$x = Order::with(array('user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id','name');
    }), 'revisions' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id','created_at','user_id','operation','text');
    })->get();
var_dump($x->user->name);
```

`$x->user` is the relation model, `user->name` is its property

So, to have it also in `revision` you have to do something like:

```
$x->each(function(&$order) { 
   $order->revisions->each(function(&$rev) use ($order) {
      $rev->setUsername($order->user->name);
   });
});
```

assuming you have a `setUsername` method in your `relation` Model. In any case, the `username` in `relation` model should be a private property, not a fillable field, because is not part of the table, and in this case you have to check if it is exported when you do a `->toJson()`

Comment: I understand that, however I expect to receive an object in the format I explain as expected result. I'm calling that query via ajax and I need the data.

Comment: you need to set the property in an explicit way, unless you want to use joins. Eloquent relations are very strict from this point of view

Comment: Well, how convenient is it to use joins? I don't like that much the approach in your answer

Comment: Using joins is definitely more efficient but you basically loose relations logic